# Attribute Changer 11

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-attributes, attributes

I have downloaded the Attribute Changer 11 but I've got stuck it has failed for some reasons on my mp3 file:

```
ZAČÁTEK ZPRACOVÁNÍ : 20:24:29

C:\Users\me\Desktop\Operads2\SPANEK\s_Ritual.mp3
```

selhalo=**failed**

```
Souhrn zpracování

1 soubor(ů) analyzováno
0 soubor(ů) vyřazeno
0 soubor(ů) změněno
1 soubor(ů) selhalo

0 složek analyzováno
0 složek vyřazeno
0 složek změměno
0 složek selhalo

Vybrané soubory a složky

C:\Users\me\Desktop\Operads2\SPANEK\s_Ritual.mp3

ZPRACOVÁNÍ UKONČENO : 20:24:30
```

**Other files were indeed attribute-access-changed** but this one has not. What's wrong ?

**EDIT**

I have tried all 4 combinations with read (write) only / (un)compressed and also I have copied to another place.
**No success at all with this.** The `mp3` extension seems to be a problem.

**Here is the snippet**

[image]

**EDIT 2**
I have changed `mp3` to `lax` then modified the attributes and then switched back to `mp3`. It **works ** in this way!

Comment: Try it again and see if it succeeds. Sometimes the file is being accessed by another app and Attribute Changer cannot get exclusive access to it.

Comment: Tell us what you tried running, as we have no idea. Which attributes did you try to change? What are the attributes of the file that failed?

Comment: @Destroy666 OK. I have right click an mp3 file and selected Change Attributes. Then I've changed Created Changed Accessed to 2010 2011 and 2012 resp. On some small file with extension `'lax` it succeeded but not with larger and `mp3` extension. I don't think that my mp3 file is being used by another app nor that it is compressed.

Comment: Edit additional info to the question, instead of commenting, please. Also, you didn't mention the attributes of the mp3 file. Right click, properties and check if it's e.g. not writable.

Comment: @harrymc All atempts to change an `mp3` file have failed.Please see the snippet in my OQ.  What's going on here ??

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the Attribute Changer developer has some special
code for changing the metadata of mp3 files that is included inside
the file, not only the Windows attributes, and this code fails.

When you changed the extension from `mp3` to `lax` this worked
because Attribute Changer then didn't try to go into the file
and contented itself with changing the Windows attributes.

I note that I'm using the older Attribute Changer version 10.10a,
and I managed just now to set the modified date without problem
of an mp3 file.
This might be a bug in version 11, and in that case you should
signal it to the developer.

Comment: Great. In fact I was trying to do the following thing: I wanted that in my Psychowalkman AVS device the file with changed `mp3` and `lax` attributes on miniSD card that file would appear as **first one** I'm always getting it the last one regardless of what I try. Be it naming start with `aa` or changing the attributes file.